# phonegap + jquery mobile, good practices

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

until now I was not using this index.js that Phonegap recommends :

```
var app = {
// Application Constructor
initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
},
// Bind Event Listeners
//
// Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
// 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
},
// deviceready Event Handler
//
// The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
// function, we must explicity call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
},
// Update DOM on a Received Event
receivedEvent: function(id) {
    var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
    var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
    var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

    listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

    console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
}
};
```

Where should I put my own js functions and events (all my js file), into this, out of this, in another file ?

Where should I call those js files and where should I call the app.initialize, in relation to the position of the calls to the js files ?

Here's my html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height,width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
      </script>

    <script src="js/jquery.mobile.config.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-geturlvar.js"></script>
    <script src="js/boardDims.js"></script>
    <script src="js/functions.js"></script>
<!--        <script src="cordova.js"></script>-->
</head>
<body>
```

For now I am compiling using the remote service : $ phonegap remote run android

It would be really useful to have a default template of an app using Phonegap + JQM, for beginners like me ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That index.js is included as an example, you don't really need to use it. It is basically showing you how to work with `ondeviceready`. You need to use `ondeviceready` when you work with plugins, since most of their calls will only be available after `ondeviceready` has been fired. So you hook up your calls to plugins on a listener to `ondeviceready`. I am doing it like this for instance:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function onLoad() {
                document.addEventListener("deviceready", MYAPP.events.onDeviceReady, false);
           }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="onLoad();">
```

And inside MYAPP.events.onDeviceReady I do the calls to geolocation, camera, or whatever plugin I'm working with.

BTW, two important things to notice in you example: You need to include `cordova.js` before you can access `ondeviceready` or work with any plugin, plus you are including `index.js` twice. Perhaps you duplicated the `<script src="js/index.js"></script>` to edit it and include `js/cordova.js` and forgot to change the name/path?

Apart from that, what I do is separating the app's JS and the external libs in two separate directories for better organisation, like "lib" and "js", so you would include "js/functions.js" and "lib/jquery.js".

I include both the libs and custom JS files at the bottom of the body tag for a slight better performance: [Where should I put <script> tags in HTML markup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-is-the-best-place-to-put-script-tags-in-html-markup)

And I name the files under "js" (custom JS files for the app) according to their purpose/content, like: events.js, models.js, settings.js, util.js, ... You can see in the snippet above that I have "namespaced" my custom JS objects under the capitalised name of the app, so everything in util.js will be called like: `MYAPP.util.formatDate()`.

Comment: thanks a lot for your precise and kind answer. Indeed I included index.js twice, my mistake !  Thanks for the "the best place to put <script>" I was not sure and now I am.  What I don't understand is the difference/relationship between initialize and onDeviceReady... It's not clear to me yet